# how to align bootstrap-4 card when the first card-header has word break and the second card-header not

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a little project for myself right now, with bootstrap 4.
However I have stumbled upon a problem. I use the class card for my gallery, but one card-header has a 'white-space' set, so it breaks the word, while the other card-header does not contain a 'white-space'. This only happens on a laptop screen. On phone screens etc all works, and on a desktop it works fine aswell.

I have tried using CSS3 it's media query, or to set the cards their margin-bottom to 0, in the hopes of aligning it at the bottom of the row, but unforatunately nothing has helped me so far. I have looked on StackOverflow for a related problem and all I could find was people having problems aligning elements INSIDE the card-body, but I wish to have the card classes, no matter word break or not, to be aligned.
Somehow I cannot use the link to refer to my picture, so here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evJWh.jpg

how my html and css looks like:

```
.whiteSpaceNotAllowed {
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.whiteSpaceAllowed {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .whiteSpaceAllowed {
        white-space: normal;
    }
}

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card gallerijCard">
            <div class="card-header GallerijCardHeader">
                <center><p>Ontwerp <span class="whiteSpaceAllowed">& interieur</span></p></center>
                <!-- the span class whiteSpaceAllowed = white-space -> wrapped -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <!-- not relevent code -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--ending col-lg-3 class-->
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="card gallerijCard">
            <div class="card-header GallerijCardHeader">
                <center><p><span class="whiteSpaceNotAllowed">Renovatie</span></p></center>
                <!-- whiteSpaceNotAllowed class = white-space -> normal -->
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <!-- not relevent code -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!--ending col-lg-3 class-->
</div> <!-- ending row-->
```

So to explain what I am trying to accomplish:

The word 'Ontwerp & interieur' should break on a laptop screen, but both cards should be aligned next to each other.

Comment: You can set a min-height of your .card-header div

Answer (score 0):

// The solution is simple Nicky all you have to do is to set a min-height for all the cards in the gallery. you set min-height on the this sections of your code as show below you can change the value to suit your need.

```
<div class="col-lg-3" style='min-height: 300px'>
    <div class="card gallerijCard">
        <div class="card-header GallerijCardHeader">
            <center><p>Ontwerp <span class="whiteSpaceAllowed">& interieur</span></p></center>
            <!-- the span class whiteSpaceAllowed = white-space -> wrapped -->
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <!-- not relevent code -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```